# How to reset the alignment of physics bodies in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, gameplay-kit

I´ve made a game with SpriteKit with different bricks falling down on a hill. When these physical bodies fall down they usually bounce off the hill and change their alignment(they spin a couple of times). If I transition to the GameOver scene and press replay(back to the GameScene) the physics bodies are still aligned like when I left the scene. But I want them to have a horizontal alignment like in the beginning.

GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

 let hillTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "HillIllustration")
 let hillIllustration = SKSpriteNode(texture: hillTexture)

 let brickTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BrickIllustration")
 let brick = SKSpriteNode(texture: brickTexture)

 class GameScene: SKScene {

    //Hill

    hillIllustration.setScale(0.7)
    hillIllustration.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height * 0.16)
    hillIllustration.zPosition = 2
    hillIllustration.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: clipPath)
    hillIllustration.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    hillIllustration.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Hill
    hillIllustration.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(hillIllustration)

    //The brick is a child of the hill node

    brick.setScale(1)
    brick.position = CGPoint(x: -350, y: self.size.height * 0.5)
    brick.zPosition = 1
    brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: clipPath2)
    brick.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    brick.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Brick
    brick.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    hillIllustration.addChild(brick)

}
```

Transition to GameOver:

```
let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0)
let gameScene = GameOver(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
```

Transition back to GameScene:

```
let transition = SKTransition.crossFade(withDuration: 0)
    let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
```

Somehow when I transition scenes the information of how the bricks were aligned gets saved. How can I change that?

Comment: How are you transitioning between scenes,  I have 2 answers I can give you, but I need to know what you are doing first.

Comment: I updated my question. @KnightOfDragon

Comment: No, how do you replay

Comment: Do you mean how I go back to the GameScene? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Yes that is your problem, is it not?

Comment: I updated my question again. But it ´s basically the same approach. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: This does not fit your question, you are using a new scene which means it cant be the old way

Comment: I just want to know why the GameScene doesn't get reset when I leave the Scene. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: No idea, what you are posting does not reflect your question

Comment: What were your two answers? @Knight0fDragon

Comment: They do not apply here.  You are creating a new scene which means it is impossible for it to not reset

Comment: Do you know why the physics bodies change their alignment? It´s like when a car falls on the hill and then lands on its roof, the next time I transition to the game scene the car falls upside down like with the wheels on top. @Knight0fDragon

Comment: No idea, you need to make a minimal complete verifiable example,  your code now works correcty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want that after you restart the game the brick node go back to start rotation than call:

```
brick.zRotation = 0
```

if you want that during the game the node do not rotate than you may put this code in the update func that already have in all spritekit files:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
 brick.zRotation = 0
}
```

Hope this helps